# Strawberry sauce fermented in fridge?

Tags: food-safety

I left a tiny plastic take-out container of strawberry or raspberry sauce for cheesecake from a restaurant in the fridge a little too long and it was bulging and leaking. I am not eating it but wondering about clean up. Since it should be acidic/sweet is this likely a fermentation thing, not a botulism thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*C. botulinum* germinates when there is no oxygen, generates toxin when dying and [doesn't like low pH](https://extension.colostate.edu/topic-areas/nutrition-food-safety-health/botulism-9-305/) (below 4.6), [so you should be safe](https://www.clemson.edu/extension/food/food2market/documents/ph_of_common_foods.pdf).

If the container is airtight, there is still a possibility of some spores (if they're present due to improper cooking and handling) germinating and then dying, so your sauce could still contain trace amounts of toxin, but it looks like a very remote possibility.

In case you want to be absolutely sure, toss the entire thing out and cover the spill with a 1:4 v/v bleach solution, paper towels and let it sit for 15 minutes. Then remove the towels and clean with water and soap to remove the bleach. Wash your hands thoroughly. More details [here](https://extension.wsu.edu/foodsafety/what-you-need-to-know-about-botulism/)